# Various uses of the English "for" to indicate purpose

Tags: translation, word-choice, usage, difference

The sentences below all use the word "for" to indicate purpose. I tried to think of a few sentences that may use "for" a little bit differently. Can you help me understand how to use "for" in Chinese?

How would you translate "do you have a microwave for guests to use?" Is it: “你有一个客人可以用的微波炉吗？” is there a better way to say that?

Also:
"This microwave is for guests use only."

"Is this gift for me?"

"That chair is not made for adults. It is only for kids."

Comment: Your example is ok. Note that there isn't a match of "for" in Chinese. So the translation could be various. I would say: 你有客用微波炉吗？（brief） 这台微波炉仅供宾客使用。（polite）/此微波炉仅供客用。（brief） 这是给我的礼物吗？那椅子并非做给成人，只是童用。（literary）/那把椅子不是做给大人用的，小孩子才可以坐（colloquial）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to say it.
你有给客人用的微波炉吗？
你有一台微波炉好给客人用吗？
你有给客人用的微波炉吗？

“Is this gift for me?"
这个礼物是给我的吗？
这是给我的礼物吗？

"That chair is not made for adults. It is only for kids."
这把椅子不是给成人制作的，只是给孩子的。

Comment: Down vote for abusing “个”

Comment: if you say "have one microwave" then means"有一个微波炉"@TooskyHierot

Comment: I mean abusing 个 reflects "Europeanization" in language. We do not use 一+量词（mostly 个） for no purpose. "One" or "a" in English doesn't mean we must add “一个” in Chinese. It only makes the sentence wordy and sounding "translationese". By the way, “一台微波炉”/“一把椅子”/“一份/件/样礼物” not 个 everywhere.

Comment: 你有一台给客人用的微波炉吗？it is ok.

Comment: I am chinese I think both is ok.

Comment: Valid indeed, but not orthodox or good.

Answer (score 1):

As daotian answered, “for” as used in your three sentences would be best translated by 给.

For other uses of “for,” see https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/for:

> intended to be given to = 给
>
> having the purpose of = 为了
>
> because of = 因为，由于；作为…的结果